# naiveBayes command gives probabilities larger than zero

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian

I am trying to perform a Naive Bayes classifier on a simple dataset. The three variables that I have are `weight` (continuous), `BP` (continuous), and `disease` (dichotomous).

When I write the command for naive Bayes, some of the results give me a probability (much) larger than one. I have also tried it through 'e1071' and 'klaR'.

Please see my code below:

```
> install.packages("e1071")

> library(e1071)

> mydata$disease<-as.factor(mydata$disease)

> classifier<- naiveBayes(disease ~ weight + BP, mydata, laplace = 0, subset, na.action = na.pass)

> Please see my results below,

> A-priori probabilities:

> Y

>    0    1 

> 0.47 0.53 

> Conditional probabilities:

>    weight

> Y        [,1]     [,2]

>   0  69.10638 27.22869

>   1 131.22642 39.47377

>    BP

> Y       [,1]     [,2]

>   0 44.78723 21.73350

>   1 35.81132 13.55623
```

As seen above, one of the probabilities is 44.78723. Is that correct? I've tried klaR as well and it gives me very similar results. Help?

Comment: Are you sure the results are the probabilities and not the likelihoods or log likelihoods?  Naive Bayes does its calculations in the likelihood space, so that might be how R outputs them.

Comment: its the mean and standard deviation. From the help of `?naiveBayes` ; `For each numeric variable, a table giving, for each target class, mean and standard deviation of the (sub-)variable).` Check for `weight` ;`aggregate(weight~disease, data=mydata, function(i) c(mean(i), sd(i)))`

Comment: @GordonLinoff what confuses me the most is that it's titled _Conditional_ _Probabilities_ so I'm unsure that they would me likelihood.

Comment: @user2957945 I ran the code and it gave me the following:           `aggregate(weight~disease, data=mydata, function(i) c(mean(i), sd(i))) 
  disease  weight.1  weight.2
1       0        NA 0.2470922
2       1        NA 0.4343722
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(i) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(i) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: The error suggests an issue with the `class` of your variables, for example `mean(factor(1))` produces a similar error to what you received. Can you post the output from `str(mydata$weight)` and `str(mydata$disease)`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade comment:

The output gives the parameters (mean and standard deviation) of the normal distribution for each level of the class variable. From the `?naiveBayes` help:

```
For each numeric variable, a table giving, for each target class, mean and 
standard deviation of the (sub-)variable)
```

Run a small example to see this, using the `iris` dataset:

```
library(e1071)

# load iris dataset and set some values to missing
data(iris)
iris$Sepal.Length[1] <- NA
iris$Petal.Width[2] <- NA
iris$Species[3] <- NA

# run naive Bayes model
(m <- naiveBayes(Species ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Width , data = iris, na.action=na.omit))
```

This produces the output

```
# Naive Bayes Classifier for Discrete Predictors
# 
# Call:
#   naiveBayes.default(x = X, y = Y, laplace = laplace)
# 
# A-priori probabilities:
#   Y
# setosa versicolor  virginica 
# 0.3197279  0.3401361  0.3401361 
# 
# Conditional probabilities:
#   Sepal.Length
# Y                [,1]      [,2]
# setosa     5.012766 0.3603241
# versicolor 5.936000 0.5161711
# virginica  6.588000 0.6358796
# 
# Petal.Width
# Y                 [,1]      [,2]
# setosa     0.2489362 0.1080908
# versicolor 1.3260000 0.1977527
# virginica  2.0260000 0.2746501
```

Check that the tables give the mean and st. dev for each continuous variable at each level of `Species`

```
aggregate(cbind(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width) ~ Species, data=iris, 
                        function(i) c(mean(i), sd(i)))

# Species Sepal.Length.1 Sepal.Length.2 Petal.Width.1 Petal.Width.2
# 1     setosa      5.0127660      0.3603241     0.2489362     0.1080908
# 2 versicolor      5.9360000      0.5161711     1.3260000     0.1977527
# 3  virginica      6.5880000      0.6358796     2.0260000     0.2746501
```